# transparent textbox not showing text after i leave the textbox

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

i made this class for transparent textbox

```
public partial class TransTextBox : TextBox
{
    public TransTextBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
                 ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                 ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                 ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                 ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

but as i leave the textbox the text disappears but is still there. How to fix it?

Comment: If the `TextBox` is transparent, so is the text inside of it. I think what you want is a `Label`. What is the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AustinWBryan , I am trying to make a textbox that blends with background. example : i typed my name : AKC and as i leave, the textbox's text appears in a black color(or any) like a label.
I have noticed some effects in this transTextBox that i can't choose a font and transparency disappears if I set UserPaint to false

Comment: If this is WinForms: You cannot do that. Backgrounds cannot "shine through". Probably using WPF or HTML is an alternative option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is removing your `ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer` flag and then Redraw the text by `DrawString` on the `OnPaint` event

Something like this:

```
public partial class TransTextBox : TextBox {
    public TransTextBox() {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |
            //ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | //comment this flag out
                         ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                         ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                         ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    private void redrawText() {
        using (Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics())
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor))
            graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, brush, 1, 1); //play around with how you draw string more to suit your original
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        redrawText();
    }
}
```

If you use `DoubleBuffer`, even you redraw the string, your string will get "erased" by the double.

Comment: JESUS CHRIST ! IT WORKED!, thanks Ian but there is one more thing. As I type in anything in the font i chose is not being used instead its some fixed sys type font. you try it in your visual studio then you will understand.
you can follow properties I am using for textbox
its transparent in back color, uses calbri 8pt  and everything is normal

Comment: @AKC I see the problem... that is because once you have `UserPaint` Control style, then everything gets more complicated - but unfortunarely in this case you cannot help but use it. Perhaps the best way is to change `this.Font` in the `DrawString` with `new Font()` and adjusting its font family, size, type, etc, accordingly. This way, you can redraw the exact font style with what you use to write.

Comment: and yes, how to use the password char, the password char goes great but as i leave the box the password gets shown, its like when you are typing you get the password char but when you leave, its normal font. how to fix that bro?

Comment: For password, perhaps for that special text box, instead of drawing string, you simply need to draw the black circle (yes, the character named "black circle"). I am not sure if it can be done by unicode character, but by right it should. You can try it out, I never try it, however. Unicode for black circle is U+25CF. And you can also let me know if you are successful. ;)

Comment: if you meant to use the  little dot thingie then yes i tried pressing Alt + 1097 or something like that to get the dot but it didn't work.  is there any override void for password char? or something else that can help? please

Comment: I mean, currently you use `this.Text` in the `DrawString`. And as long as `this.Text` is in the current format, it can never be hidden. You should check string with "\u" input. I think string str = "\u25cf" might give you unicode for black circle.

Comment: Sorry, I think you should use "\u2022" instead for black **dot**. "\u25cf" is black **circle**.

Comment: dude this is working  i have changed this.Text to this
' graphics.DrawString(this.Text ="\u25cf", this.Font, brush, 1, 1);'
but only 1 black dot is showing but your  solution is awesome (y)

Comment: I see. You need to count the text.Length and the create as many dots as the text.Length. Anyway, I think all these are minors. Now that you solve your biggest problem in the code, I believe you can proceed rather smoothly, friend. ;)

Comment: thank you so much Ian for your help, i am just going to change the dots by getting the TransTextBox1.Text.Length and setting dots to that length when the text box is left using the events and hope this works and I think this will work fine, if not I will let you know :) thanks again dude, merry Christmas

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

You can create an object that contains a `TextBox` and `Label` and the focus enters the `TextBox`, hide the `Label`, and when the focus leaves the `TextBox`, show the `Label`. That will fix your current setup now.

I more direct approach might be something like this:

```
public class TransTextBox
{
    BackColor = this.Parent.BackColor;
}
```

But if the background color changes, this needs to be called again.